# hits addon is not working on multiple sites

Tags: devdemon

hits addon downloaded from http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/hits not working on other sites I have three website

1) exampleone.com
2) exampletwo.com
3) examplethree.com

exampletwo.com,examplethree.com are fetching data from exampleone.com using site="short_name" here is example:-

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" site="default_site" limit="1"  track_views="one" dynamic="no" status="open|featured" disable="categories|category_fields|pagination|member_data"}

          {exp:hits:count_hits entry_id="{entry_id}"}

   {/exp:channel:entries}
```

now when i put hits adddon as per there documentation its not working on 
exampletwo.com,examplethree.com and its only working on exampleone.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: I saw you posted a support ticket. We replied the same day. I want to make sure it didn't go to your spam folder.

Comment: Are you showing content from exampleone on exampletwo? If so hits data on exampletwo will show on exampleone as it is exampleone content.